# How to extract grammar rules from a language (grammar induction?) using a neural network like a LSTM

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar

I have a simple artificial language. It has about 200 words and it has a grammar. I am trying to figure out how to learn that grammar, which I think is called grammar induction, then print those rules. I have found a few papers specifically about what I want to do but 2 are in Chinese and the other was way over my head because I am new to NLP. I am looking for, if possible, very simple example in that I learn better by reading code than papers. Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Also I should add my corpus will contain conversations between 2 entities.

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? Do you want it to give you, say, a series of CFG rules for the syntax?

Comment: Anything readable by a human such as if then type rules a state diagram, relationship map. Basically some that says like all sentences start with A except when message Y then sentence starts with b.

Comment: If it has only 200 words, I guess its corpus is extremely small, so I don't think NLP will help you: any decently powerful neural network will simply "memorize" the entire corpus (i.e., its output will be made of fragments you already have in the corpus).

Comment: I should say this is a start. Latter will have much more as well as very complex state machines. I think in NLP that's automata?

Comment: Also I don't want fragments. I really need the rules and syntax.

Comment: No, it's not about how complex the state machines can get. It's about the size of corpus. To do anything interesting with NLP, you need large data: for context, the entire work of Shakespeare is frequently used as a _toy_ dataset (just to demonstrate how the algorithm works).

Comment: @jick: I interpreted the first sentence as 'It has about 200 words *in the lexicon*'. If I understand the question correctly, OP is testing the system using this artificial language with a very small lexicon, and can probably generate as large a corpus as he needs using the underlying artificial language. OP, am I right in my interpretation?

Comment: I literally have access to terabytes. It's from a malware data protocol training corpus for something different, firewalls and packet inspection. I want to see if I can make a model that can take a sample, let's say a few gigabytes to start, and model the protocol which for all intents and purposes is a language. I've seen a few papers on this topic about using grammar induction but either I could not read them or I did not understand the model

Comment: @waveswithhands yes exactly. The language is a made up malware with a made up protocol for some other folks project. I am interested if I can us it, induce the grammar or FSMs, and then print them out as rules or a state diagram. There are a lot of reasons why this would be useful but I'm looking for a simple example in Keras or Tensorflow. What I have seen in scholarly work is very hard for me to follow ;+)

Comment: Can you tell us more about the language? Where does it fall on the Chomsky hierarchy? If you don't know what that means, can you tell whether there's a fixed sentence length  or maximum sentence length? If sentences can be unbounded, is it because elements can be repeated, or is it because they're nested? Would it make sense to draw a parse tree? NLP parsers usually assume a Context Free Grammar, but your language might be simpler than that. You mention FSMs, which implies that you have a Regular Grammar, and that's simpler than what NLP usually assumes.

Comment: Do you have anyone who knows a lot about the grammar who can label it. If you wanted to parse English, you would probably start by training a parser on a collection of text that's been carefully labeled by someone who knows the language, such as the Penn Treebank, which consists of one parse tree per sentence. If you don't have a collection of parse trees, what you are making is an unsupervised parser.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The language is a network protocol. I can tag all elements as I said i know the vocab. What I want to do is get the rules of the language, a network protocol in this case, even if I have not seen the specific protocol before. So the project would start with fake protocols where I do know the rules etc to test. The goal though would be to move to protocols that are unknow like those found in malware.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't a standard task. If you can answer some of the questions in my previous posts, I can figure out what standard task is closest to what you want, and I can try to find a relevant research paper with a public code base. If you have a language that can be modeled with a FSM, you can look at this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/can-finite-state-machines-be-encoded-as-input-output-for-a-neural-network. Sentences in human languages cannot be represented by FSMs, so that's a totally different class of problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Papers With Code](https://www.paperswithcode.com/) probably has precisely what you're looking for. Search for your paper in there. As for libraries, [Keras](https://keras.io/) is super simple to get started with. Can get it stand-alone or included in TensorFlow which includes many advanced useful tools.

Comment: Thank you I am using keras and tensorflow or pytorch. The examples I have see of grammar induction where to complex for me. I need some simpler. I did review papers with code and saw two examples but each is several thousand lines of code and I am not sure they do what I am interested in. That being said I am learning about a topic I have almost no knowledge of so that's food